# The right way to wrap a non-generic class with a generic one

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to wrap (and simplify) the [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) library in my project like this:

```
public class MapDbPersistentStorage<V>
{
    private DB db;
    private HTreeMap<String, V> storage;

    public MapDbPersistentStorage(String filename)
    {
        db = DBMaker
                .fileDB(filename)
                .fileMmapEnable()
                .make();

        storage = (HTreeMap<String, V>) db
                .hashMap("section", Serializer.STRING, Serializer.LONG)
                .createOrOpen();
    }

    public V get(String key, V defaultValue)
    {
        return storage.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public void set(String key, V value)
    {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }

    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

As it's been pointed out, the problem is the `Serializer.LONG` part (it's supposed to be of type `V`). I need to come up with a serializer based on the generic type provided. What's the right way to do so?

Comment: Pass the `Serializer` to use to the constructor of your wrapper.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I'll be passing the `Long` type twice then? Once as a generic parameter and once as a constructore parameter? Don't you think that's a bad idea since one can provide two incompatible types?

Comment: Yes, but you _need_ it twice, one at compile time (the generic type) and one at runtime (the `Serializer`). If you want to make it safer, you could wrap the `Serializer` in a generic interface that has the generic type of the serializer, then require that interface as an argument.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the statement "I need it twice"! I mean Java might, but *I* need it once. Could you please write your solution as I'm not sure what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses erasure to implement it's generics. At runtime, your class has no idea what `V` you used to instantiate it with. That information is not retained at runtime.

So if you *need* it at runtime, you're going to have to manually retain it. But in your current program, the compiler has no idea how the type `Long` should relate to `Serailizer.Long`.

To be (somewhat) typesafe, you could wrap the `Serializer` in a generic class or interface which generic type corresponds to the type encoded by the serialzer. Effectively provide a way to link the 2 type systems.

```
interface GenericSerializer<T> extends Supplier<Serializer> {

    public static GenericSerializer<Long> ofLong() {
        return () -> Serializer.Long;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class MapDbPersistentStorage<V> {
    private DB db;
    private HTreeMap<String, V> storage;
    private final Serializer ser;

    public MapDbPersistentStorage(GenericSerializer<V> serFactory) {
        this.ser = serFactory.get();
    }

    public MapDbPersistentStorage(String filename) {
        db = DBMaker
                .fileDB(filename)
                .fileMmapEnable()
                .make();

        storage = (HTreeMap<String, V>) db
                .hashMap("section", Serializer.STRING, ser)
                .createOrOpen();
    }

    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
MapDbPersistentStorage<Long> m = new MapDbPersistentStorage<>(GenericSerializer.ofLong());
```

Where the compiler can check that the type of the `GenericSerializer` corresponds to that of the `MapDbPersistentStorage`.

Comment: Thanks but how this has eliminated providing the `Long` type twice? You are still naming it as a generic parameter as well as in the constructor parameter!

Comment: @Mehran You can't get around that, and the answer explains why. At least this provides some compile time check that you pass in the intended `Serializer`.

Comment: How about defining a `private V dummy;` and trying to work its type at runtime?

Comment: @Mehran 1.) You'd have to pass in the actual dummy object, which would have a reference to it's class. At runtime the field's static type is just `Object` (due to erasure). 2.) You'd also have to somehow translate that type into the corresponding `Serializer`.